# Accessing an IIS Express site from a remote computer with SSL enabled

Tags: wcf, ssl, iis

Using [this guide](http://johan.driessen.se/posts/Accessing-an-IIS-Express-site-from-a-remote-computer) I managed to access my server from remote hosts. However, now I want to enable SSL on my server and I know that there is an option in the configuration to enable SSL but the https URL added is on localhost. How do I do the same as in the tutorial but with SSL, just add another binding but with port 443? or is there something more to it.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to use IISExpress instead of IIS on the server? Whichversion of OS have the server? If you write about accessing from a remote computer hen you mean access over Internet or access from other computers of the local LAN?

Comment: @Oleg I am currently using IIS express yes. If I understand the question it's on windows. At least for now I'm talking about access from other computers on LAN.